Velo file upload to Collection from upload button problem
my problem is that when I upload a file with the uploadButton it envokes the onChange() which in its turn calls the uploadFiles() and that returns an array of the files. From there I use a variable to store the result and then I get the 1st array element's fileUrl using this uploadResults[0].fileUrl . So all is good and I get the URL, but upon upload to my Collection when I submit the form, the image does not show up. I have uploaded another image manually, and from what I can see the URL's have the same format, but one is valid and the other is not. The only difference is that one is uploaded in the Site Files, and the other in Visitor Uploads.
URL of the code uploaded image
"wix:image://v1/2fb1f8_7d5c9aab31b94162bdb414729309ce3f~mv2.jpg/cheerful-indian-photographer-with-backpack-holding-2023-11-27-04-57-44-utc%20(1).jpg#originWidth=400&originHeight=400"
URL of manually uploaded image
"wix:image://v1/41615d_fd2d136ba5ea409e821a9eb0e2c661fe~mv2.jpg/photographer-speaking-to-client-in-studio-2023-11-27-05-05-38-utc(1).jpg#originWidth=400&originHeight=400"
How it appears in the Collection
As you can see Wix does not recognize this url, i have tried with other formats and other images, smaller sizes, bigger sizes, other buttons.
The code below is what I am using, it is a snippet of only the file upload as the other functionality is working as intended. Would really appreciate the help on this one.
import wixData from 'wix-data';
import { authentication, currentMember } from 'wix-members-frontend';

$w.onReady(async () => {
  // Wait for current member to resolve
  const user = await currentMember.getMember();

  $w('#uploadButton1').onChange(async() => {
    const uploadResults = await $w('#uploadButton1').uploadFiles();
    console.log(uploadResults);
  });

  $w('#button14').onClick(async(uploadResults) => {
    await handleFormSubmission(user);
    await createLinkedContact(uploadResults);
  });

 

});


async function createLinkedContact(uploadResults) {

   const linkedContact = {
    firstName: $w('#input49').value,
    lastName: $w('#input48').value,
    email: $w('#input47').value,
    image: uploadResults[0].fileUrl,
    phoneNumber: Number($w('#input46').value),
    date: $w('#datePicker1').value.toISOString().split('T')[0],
  };

  try {
    // Insert the linked contact into the Testing collection
    const insertedLinkedContact = await wixData.insert('Testing', linkedContact);
    console.log('Linked contact created:', insertedLinkedContact);
    // Optionally, you can update the member profile or perform additional actions
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error inserting linked contact into Testing collection:', error);
  }
}


So as it seems this was my problem.
 $w.onReady(async () => {
  // Wait for current member to resolve
  const user = await currentMember.getMember();

  let uploadedImage; // Declare a variable to store the uploaded image

  $w('#uploadButton1').onChange(async () => {
    let imageCollection = await $w('#uploadButton1').uploadFiles();
    uploadedImage = imageCollection[0]; // Store the uploaded image in the variable
  });

  await handleFormSubmission(user);

  $w('#button14').onClick(async () => {
    if (uploadedImage) {
      await handleFormSubmission(user);
      await createLinkedContact(uploadedImage, user);
    } else {
      console.log("No image uploaded");
    }
  });


async function createLinkedContact(uploadedImage, user) {
    let fullImgURL = `https://static.wixstatic.com/media/${uploadedImage.fileName}`;

    const linkedContact = {
      firstName: $w('#input49').value,
      lastName: $w('#input48').value,
      email: $w('#input47').value,
      image: fullImgURL,
      phoneNumber: Number($w('#input46').value),
      date: $w('#datePicker1').value.toISOString().split('T')[0],
    };

So from what I saw the imageURL has to start with this https://static.wixstatic.com/media/{image-name}
Then when it gets added to the Collection, the image will appear.

You can't get the file URL from uploadResults. That's just the array of the files that will be uploaded once you click the button that triggers the upload.
Here's the typical upload process:
$w("#myUploadButton").fileType = "Image"; // Site visitor can choose an image
$w("#myButton").onClick(() => {
  if ($w("#myUploadButton").value.length > 0) {
    // Site visitor chose a file
    console.log("Uploading the following files:");
    $w("#myUploadButton")
      .uploadFiles()
      .then((uploadedFiles) => {
        uploadedFiles.forEach((uploadedFile) => {
          console.log("File url:" + uploadedFile.fileUrl);
        });
        console.log("Upload successful.");
      })
      .catch((uploadError) => {
        console.log("File upload error: " + uploadError.errorCode);
        console.log(uploadError.errorDescription);
      });
  } else {
    // Site visitor clicked button but didn't choose a file
    console.log("Please choose a file to upload.");
  }
});


It may sound stupid, but just in case, I was facing the same issue.
$w('uploadButton')
I was forgetting the #.
Nope, I am not a new programmer, I am experienced.
